# How to edit "labeled" number in Manipulate plot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

i have a question, i use a ManipulatePlot function, i added a number after a slider by adding:

```
Appearance->"Labeled"
```

The whole code is here:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Function[1, y, f], {y, -2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]}, PlotRange -> {{-2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]}, {-0.65, 1}}], {f, 0, Pi/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

And now i would like to:

1.change the size of the number shown

2.Show in the slider not the exact number of the parameter f, but multiplied by Pi, so that the numbers shown will change like: 0...intermediate number*Pi...Pi

thanks a lot for help

Comment: `Function[1, y, f]` is a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Sin[f y]` in place of `Function[1, y, f]`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[f  y], {y, -2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]}, {-0.65, 1}}], 
 Row[{Control[{f, 0, Pi/2}], Style[Row[{Dynamic[f], π}, Spacer[1]], 16, Red]}, Spacer[2]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use

```
Row[{Control[{f, 0, Pi/2}], Dynamic@Style[Round[f, π/64], 24, Red] }, Spacer[2]]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much kglr.

Comment: @MaciekKowalczyk, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: How can i change precision of the number shown?

Comment: @Maciek, you can use `Row[{Dynamic[Round[f, .001]], \[Pi]}, Spacer[1]]` to show 3 digits after  the decimal point.